# How to replace predict_classes() in R?

Tags: r, tensorflow, binary, classification

I would like to post a confusion matrix from this binary classification

```
classes <- model %>% predict_classes(X_test, batch_size = batch_size)
```

With

```
table(y_test, classes)
```

Since the predict_classes method is deprecated and was removed from tensorflow in version 2.6., I wonder what the solution must look like.

Or do I just not understand the fix below?

The error code tells me:

- if your model does binary classification
  (e.g. if it uses a `sigmoid` last-layer activation).

  ```
  model %>% predict(x) %>% `>`(0.5) %>% k_cast("int32")
  ```

Does someone encounter the same issue? For multi-class classification, it seems to work.

It is an example from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/code/rtatman/beginner-s-intro-to-rnn-s-in-r/notebook)